# How to force background down whole page when content overflows?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a gradient background with the main content of my website in a separate `div` with its own background color.

When the height of the `div` is less than the height of the page, everything seems to display fine. However, when the height of the `div` is greater than the height of the page/window (the content overflows off screen), the background gradient seems to stop.

This JSFiddle illustrates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/AEpE5/

If you increase the height of the result window so that the content `div` is completely contained, you can see the background gradient displays nicely beneath the content. But if you decrease the height of the result window (or simply add more content within the `div`) so that the content `div` is not completely contained in the result window and then scroll down (so as to see the rest of the content in the `div`), you can see that the background gradient seems to end.

Obviously I want my background gradient to continue down the entire page (until I reach the end of my content, not just to the end of the window). How would that be accomplished?

Comment: You need to provide some code in your question not just a fiddle [discussed in meta here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201633/does-a-fiddle-provide-enough-information-to-describe-the-specific-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will stop the gradient.

http://jsfiddle.net/AEpE5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `body {...}` to `html, body {...}`

http://jsfiddle.net/gDg8p/

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AEpE5/2/

Just a note for you, the HTML does not need to be set to 100% unless you are also setting the body to 100% so your elements can be 100%.